# How do I fix Rainmeter skin displaying %'s?

Tags: text, formatting, rainmeter

I am attempting to make a basic clock skin for rainmeter, and I am following [this](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/getting-started/basic-tutorials/clock) tutorial.

When I try to use % to display a Measure, it displays the % on the skin:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajb4q.png)

Here is the code:

```
[MeterMonthDayYear]    
Meter=String    
MeterStyle=TextStyle    
MeasureName=MeasureMonthName    
MeasureName2=MeasureDayOfMonth    
MeasureName3=MeasureYear    
X=204    
Y=0R    
FontSize=13    
Text=%1 %2, %3
```

I double checked all of my measures, so that isn't the issue. It seems that rainmeter is just parsing the code wrong. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any obvious errors in the code you've pasted.

I think you'll either need to show more code (for example the measures used), or you can open the log (Right-click the skin, select `Rainmeter` -> `Manage` -> `Open Log`), then refresh your skin.
If you've made any mistakes, these will usually show up in the log as `Error`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't vote up, but thank you! I pasted the code from the tutorial project, and it worked then, so I must have been missing something small. I will keep in mind the log tool in the future. Thanks again.